# How can i prove those metrics are the equivalent?

Tags: metric-spaces

We got 2 metric spaces in $\mathbb{R}$, and these metrics: $d_1(x,y):= |x-y|$   and   $d_2(x,y):= |x^3-y^3|$. I'm asked to prove this by proving that the identity **which goes from one metric space to the other** is an homeomorphism. I'm not sure what is the identity they are speaking about here.

Comment: Two metrics... *where* ? The real line or what?

Comment: edited, yes in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Basically you have a space $X$ and there are two metrics $d_1,d_2$ on the space. The identity map is the map from $(X,d_1)$ to $(X,d_2)$ mapping $x\mapsto x$.

Comment: Every open $d_1$-ball with centre $a$ contains an open $d_2$-ball with centre $a$, and vice-versa, so the topologies are the same.

Comment: $x^3-y^3 = (x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$ hence $d_2(x,y) = d_1(x,y)|x^2+xy+y^2|$. you have to prove that if for a sequence $(y_n)$, when $n \to \infty$ : $d_1(x,y_n) \to 0$ then $d_2(x,y_n) \to 0$, and conversely if $d_2(x,y_n) \to 0$ then $d_1(x,y_n) \to 0$. this proves that the topologies induced by the metrics are the same : they define the same neighborhoods and the same converging sequences

Comment: Ok maybe the problem is i don't know how to even formulate the question, i tried with a function $f(x)=x$ and prove it is homeomorphism (because im asked to prove the identity is an homeomorphism)  but what has to do $f(x)=x$ with the given metrics? i feel im missing someting :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity is the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=x$. Here, the first $\mathbb R$ has the $d_1$ metric, and the second $\mathbb R$ has the $d_2$ metric. We need to show that $f$ is a bijection which is continuous and has a continuous inverse. It is clearly a bijection. To prove that the identity continuous, choose $x\in\mathbb R$. Let $\epsilon>0$, and let $\delta=\min\{\epsilon/(3|x|^2+3|x|+1),1\}$. Then if $d_1(x,y)<\delta$, $|y|\leq|x|+1$, and  $$d_2(f(x),f(y))=d_2(x,y)=|x^3-y^3|=|x-y||x^2+xy+y^2|$$ $$\leq|x-y|(|x|^2+|x|^2+|x|+|x|^2+2|x|+1)$$ $$<\frac{\epsilon}{3|x|^2+3|x|+1}(3|x|^2+3|x|+1)$$ $$=\epsilon.$$

Therefore the identity is continuous.

Now you need to prove that the inverse of the identity is continuous.

Comment: Looks like my  definition of identity wasnt' the problem, i was misunderstanding continuity itself. Thx a lot !!!!!!!!!

Comment: the inverse of the function f, isn't it continuous if i say "without loss of generality"?

Comment: No. There are plenty of examples of functions which are continuous whose inverses are not continuous.

Comment: but this is an identity!

Comment: Sorry. When we change our concept of what distance means, even the identity may be discontinuous. An example would be $d_3 (x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$, and $0$ if $x=y $. The identity between the regular $\mathbb R $ and $\mathbb R $ with this distance is not continuous.